# Orbit of a point.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$\newcommand{\Orb}{\operatorname{Orb}}$

Let $\Theta \in (0,1)$ be irrational. For all $x \in [0,1]$, define 
$$\Orb(x) = \{ \{x + n \Theta\} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

My question is: Is it true that $\Orb(x) = \Orb(y)$    OR   $\Orb(x) \cap \Orb(y) = \varnothing$?

I think this is true if we can show that $[0,1]$ can be partitioned into orbits of all of its points... Can someone help me to prove this in case this is true? thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the orbit doesn't have a mod $1$ in the definition somewhere? OHH that's what that extra curly bracket is for haha... (might want to emphasize it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that $x\sim y$ iff $y\in Orb(x)$ defines an equivalence
relation

Comment: So, if $y \in \Orb (x)$, then $y = \{ x + \theta k \}$ for some $k$. How can we obtain $x = \{y + \theta t \}$ for some $t$ ?

Comment: $\{x \}$ = x?????

Comment: It think it would be better to say $y =_1 x + \theta k$ the brackets are confusing.

Comment: @Citizen - What does $=_1$ means ?

Comment: it means modulo 1

Comment: @Citizen - I agree with your comment about writing $=_1$, but I will try to look at it again in the morning (its very late here)

Comment: Thanks Belgi for your help!.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Define $x\sim y$ if and only if $y-x\in\Bbb Z\Theta$, the set of integer multiples of $\Theta$, and check that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Then show that the orbits are its equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1):

On top of answers with equivalence relation hint:

Note that $\{x\} = \{y\}$ if and only if $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So if $\{x\} = \{y + \theta k\}$, then $x-y-\theta k = j \in \mathbb{Z}$, and consequently $\{x-\theta k\} = \{y\}$.  You can do all your arithmetic without taking fractional parts until the very end.

Comment: I'd say $\{x\}=\{y\}$ if and only if $x=y$.  Otherwise, e.g. $\{1\}=\{2\}$.

Comment: @Rebecca The brackets signify fractional part (the original post didn't make that clear), so $\{1\} = \{2\}$. This is also why irrationality matters, otherwise orbits may overlap.

Comment: I suppose you must be right (I'll delete my answer).  I've never seen this notation before, but I want to whack whoever invented it on the back of the head with a rolled up newspaper.