# Question about analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

We know $x \sim y$ iff $y - x \in \theta \mathbb{Z}$ (mod 1) and $\theta$ irrational defines an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$ with equivalence classes  $[x] = \{\{x + n \theta \}\} =  Orb (x)$. My professor said that by the Axiom of Choice, we can choose $S \subseteq [0,1]$ such that $S$ contain exactly one point on each orbit. Now, let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ How does it follow that $f^n(S) = \{ \{S + n \theta \} \}$ ? Also , is it true that:

$$ \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f^n(S) = [0,1]$$

$$ f^n(S) \cap f^m(S) = \varnothing $$ if $ n \neq m$ ?? I will be really grateful if someone can explain to me how these assertions follow. Thanks

Comment: I guess $f$ is supposed to be $x \mapsto x + \theta \pmod{1}$?

Comment: Recall your previous question ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/485300/91818)) where people were confused about this $\{..\}$ notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x \in S$. $f^n(x)$ will go through all of $\mathrm{Orb(x)}$ by construction. Since you have one representative of **every** orbit in $S$, $f^n(S)$ will hit all of $[0,1]$, so taking the union gives you $[0,1]$. Your second bullet point follows from the fact that orbits are disjoint (see your other question linked from Rebecca in comments).

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question: Does it follow that $m^*(f^n(S)) = m^*(S) $ ? $m^*$ denotes outer measure

Comment: also, does it follow $f^n(S) = S $?

Comment: Can show $m^\ast$ is translation invariant from construction, so yes to first question. Second question is no, because $f^n(S)$ translates the points of $S$ (modulo $1$)

Comment: Is $S$ measurable ?

Comment: you tell me , you have all the pieces

Comment: @Citizen  Suppose it is measurable and apply countable additivty to something.